# Cannot ping virtual ip from another server

Tags: linux, alias, route

I am a new member of this community and I am new to linux systems so I apologize in advance if I say something wrong.

I have created a new virtual ip: ifconfig eth1:1 192.168.0.22
I can ping eth1 from my other machine. But when I try to ping 192.168.0.22, I get a response as destination host unreachable.
Server A

```
ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0d:3a:c5:17:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.10.4/24 brd 10.0.10.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20d:3aff:fec5:1757/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0d:3a:c6:87:fc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.4/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.0.22/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global secondary eth1:1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20d:3aff:fec6:87fc/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

and my route table.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.10.1       0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.0.10.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
168.63.129.16   10.0.10.1       255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 eth0
169.254.169.254 10.0.10.1       255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth1
```

This is the Server B. I cant ping over this server.

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0d:3a:c3:4a:cb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.10.5/24 brd 10.0.10.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20d:3aff:fec3:4acb/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0d:3a:c4:15:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.5/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::3200:77f8:c9d9:d79d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.10.1       0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.0.10.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
168.63.129.16   10.0.10.1       255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 eth0
169.254.169.254 10.0.10.1       255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth1
```

Could you please give me any hints on what could be wrong? What info could I provide?

Comment: both server looks like virtual host, mac adress is from microsoft so I suppose azur hosts. did you use same network/bridge/whatever for eth1 ?

Comment: yes. these are azure hosts. I use same network for eth1. eth1s can ping each other but I don't understand why it doesn't work when it's virtual.

Comment: I do not know how Azure is configured, but ICMP Echo aka Ping is something that may or may not be allowed by firewall rules. So, just because a host cannot be reached by Ping does not mean that it cannot be reached at all, say be other means like SSH or HTTP(S).